# How many Welch plugs?

Tags: fiat, palio, freeze-plug

Fiat Palio 1.2 ED 2002

Just had 4 small and one large Welch plug replaced. Now another one is leaking.
How many Welch plugs does this vehicle have?

Comment: I assume you mean "welch" or "freeze" plug here.  I've never heard of a "Walsh" plug.

Comment: @jwh20 - I believe they are actually called ["welsh" plugs](https://www.protorqueautomotive.com.au/welsh-plugs/) or freeze plugs.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  I'm only ever heard them called "core" or "freeze" plugs.  But I think "welch" is the other term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_plug

Comment: @jwh20 - Follow my link. I think it may be a "locality" type thing (or local color). Could be called either, it would seem.

Comment: @jwh20 - Doing some research shows "Welch" may be the more correct term for this. Seems the original designer was named "Welch", so that would make sense, lol.

Comment: But to the original question...  I'm not familiar with how many of these plugs are present in the engine.  Usually there are a few.  Generally if one is leaking the others are close behind.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch; some behind the flywheel/torque converter in the bell housing. You need to find out what your problem it. When I had this problem ,it was a leaking radiator cap the was admitting fresh air in during every cool down. This produced a build up of rust in the iron block. The holes are used by the foundry to get core sand out of the castings. The name "freeze plug" is just good PR by the auto makers.